# Why can't I select the table from an excel file in a new flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have a project requiring two separate flows to pull data from excel files when uploaded to a SharePoint document library.

One flow works and allows me to pull the required data:

[image]

However the second flow does not allow me to select the required table in the 'List rows present in table' section:

[image]

I get this error when trying to select a table:

> Could not retrieve values. Value segment type 'token' expression 'outputs('Get_file_properties')?['body/{Identifier}']' invalid. Only literal segment types may be used.

I'm not sure as to why I cannot select the required table. The excel file has two tables in it. Any pointers are much appreciated.

*Edit:* Solved. I had to first select the file in the 'List rows...' section, save, run the flow and upload the document, then go back into the flow, remove the specific file name from 'List rows...' and choose "identifier". This helped flow recognise the table column names and store them, and allow dynamic file uploads to succeed if the Excel file has the correct table in it. The flow now works.

Comment: Check what happens when you enter a "custom value" (name of your table) instead of selecting it from drop-down >> Then save & run a flow once >> Then edit your flow & again try to select table name from drop-down & see if it works.

Comment: @GaneshSanap no that did not work unfortunately. If I upload the required excel file and then select it from the 'File' in 'List rows present in a table' it works, however I need the file to be dynamically noticed as this flow is based around new file uploads and one can't edit the flow every time a new file is uploaded.

Comment: hi Blar. 1) Can you add a screenshot of the Excel file that does not work? 2) Both Flows try to access the same Excel file or separate files? 3) Did you make sure your Excel file has at least one table? Simply having rows in the file is not enough. You need an actual named Table object in the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you open the excel file and select your data, then select "Format as Table" in the ribbon, it resolves it.